# Graalvm native-image windows support

Tags: graalvm-native-image

I am trying to convert my jar file using graalvm native image. However, it gives an error like,

native-image -jar NativeTest2.jar

```
Error: Platform specified as windows-amd64 isn't supported.
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below tutorials:

- [Installation on Windows Platforms](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/docs/getting-started/windows/)
- [Using GraalVM and Native Image on Windows 10](https://medium.com/graalvm/using-graalvm-and-native-image-on-windows-10-9954dc071311)
- You can install dependencies with this [file](https://github.com/tugalsan/com.tugalsan.gvm.helloworld/blob/main/VSC2022_or_Preview.vsconfig) for ease of use

With exceptions below:

- You should use English Windows (not Turkish). Windows 10/11 is okay, i did not tried below.
- You should install VS 2022.
- you should open x64 Native Tools Prompt for VS 2022